# Split number into expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this expression:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(code.dividir((Sum(Fields!PPMS_PPM.Value,"DS_DataPPMsDosAniosAnterior") 
* 1000000),Sum(Fields!PPMBSC_VentasPPM.Value,"DS_DataPPMsDosAniosAnterior"))),0,
code.dividir((Sum(Fields!PPMS_PPM.Value,"DS_DataPPMsDosAniosAnterior") * 1000000),
Sum(Fields!PPMBSC_VentasPPM.Value,"DS_DataPPMsDosAniosAnterior")))
```

Result of that is a number like: `32.3637282716252`, how can I do to get only 32 plus 2 decimal numbers like `32.36` Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pepe.. I feel these questions are pretty simple to solve if you just google it.. instead of asking such questions here..

but here is how it can be done anyway..

Right click on the text box that has this expression, properties -> formatting -> Number and then choose 2 decimal places. Done.